# org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: entity.Settings

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-orm, hibernate-5

I am trying to use Hibernate 5 (5.2.11) together with Spring ORM.

Following tutorials I came up with following configuration:

**Spring Bean**

```
<bean id="sessionFactorySettings" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/.dummy/settings</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Hibernate** (hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="entity.Settings"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This configuration leads to a `org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: entity.Settings`.

However, as soon as I move all

```
<prop key="hibernate.xxx">..</prob>
```

properties into *hibernate.cfg.xml* and I change the Spring configuration to

```
<bean id="sessionFactorySettings" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>
```

everything works fine.

Any idea what I do wrong?

PS: Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.11.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.2.11.Final'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'
}
```

Comment: I never saw the configuration you wrote. I always used or the hibernate cfg file or the spring hibernate configuration. Did you try to put the entity class list inside the spring configuration?

Comment: I thought as well that the entity class should be inside the spring configuration. But how?

Answer (score 4):

According to Spring docs, the [`LocalSessionFactoryBean`#`setMappingResources`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setMappingResources-java.lang.String...-) method should be used for providing HBM mapping files, not the Hibernate configuration file (e.g. `hibernate.cfg.xml`).

That's why it does not work. However, as soon as you use [`configLocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setConfigLocation-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) property, it works because that's the intended method for providing the Hibernate-specific configuration file.

Now, since you probably use annotations, you don't need to use `setMappingResources` at all. That's only needed if you want to use the XML_based HBM files to provide the Hibernate mappings.

What you need is [`LocalSessionFactoryBean`#`setAnnotatedClasses`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setAnnotatedClasses-java.lang.Class...-) instead. Or [`setPackagesToScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...-) which allows you to give just the `entities` folder and all entity classes inside will be registered.

Comment: I do use annotations but I thought I still need to register the classes somewhere? If I do not use any configuration for hibernate it won't work as well ...

Comment: Use `setAnnotatedClasses` as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this kind of configuration when I use hibernate and Spring:

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDatasource" />
    <!-- HERE YOU HAVE TO PUT THE PACKAGE 
         WHERE YOUR ENTITY CLASS ARE LOCATED 
         (I mean classes annotated with @Entity annotation -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="hibernate.models" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${hibernate.props.db.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                ${hibernate.props.db.show.sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                ${hibernate.props.db.generate.statistics}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                ${hibernate.props.db.format.sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                ${hibernate.props.db.ddl.instr}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.props.db.use.cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.props.db.use.query.cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">hibernateEhCacheCfg.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.props.db.jdbc.batch.size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

All my properties are, then, loaded by using a property file

I hope it's useful

Angelo